# Can [sic] be used to show an omission or error in punctuation?

Tags: punctuation

Can [sic] be used to show an omission or error in punctuation?

Eg:

Original:

He was, happy to get a raise.

Revised:

He was [sic] happy to get a raise.

**There shouldn't be a comma after 'was'.**

Original:

Mike liked lasagna, Diane preferred ziti.

Revised:

Mike liked lasagna [sic] Diane preferred ziti.

**There should be a semicolon - not a comma - between the sentences.**

Comment: *Sic* means you are quoting an error exactly as it was, and the error you show is not yours. You appear to be altering the original quotes here, which means that "sic" is inappropriate, whether or not it can be used with punctuation (which is extremely doubtful, in my opinion).

Comment: Indeed, if and when you use _sic_, you do _not_ correct any mistake: _sic_ means you are literally quoting the mistake. Whether it will be understood if you write "he was happy, [sic] to get a raise." will depend largely on your audience, I assume.

Comment: Based on your example, this could probably work too: Mike liked lasagna, [sic] Diane preferred ziti.